# object leaked:allocated object is not referenced later

Tags: iphone

When i am analyzing it getting these messages:

Method returns an Objective-C object with a +1 retain count for the below statement

```
self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

Object leaked alocated object is not refrenced later in this execution path and has a retain count of + 1

```
[self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
```

Anyone knows how to fix these messages.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Did you try balancing the alloc of the view with a release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

self.view is a @property that is retained when it is set. You will need to release it.

Try:

```
UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]; 
self.view = newView; 
[newView release];
```

or

```
self.view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `view`is a property with a `retain` attribute `self.view` retains the view so the retain created by `initWithFrame` is the additional retain that needs to be released.

SImple `autorelease`:

```
UIView *newView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
```

Better yet, if possible use ARC. ARC is available for iOS 4.x and above and on a file-by-file basis for a mixed implementation. Then, there are no `retain`, `release` or `autorelease` calls in the app.